# Use of Absolute vs. Differential Pressure Transducers to Calculate Flow Through Annular Restriction

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, pressure, airflow

If using a laminar flow element, in conjunction with Poiseuille's equation, to calculate mass and volumetric flow rate, what would the benefit be to using two absolute pressure transducers to measure dP instead a single differential transducer? I am currently using a single differential sensor and a single absolute (for STP & mass flow calculations), but have become aware of an instrument that uses 3 absolute sensors to accomplish the same calculations. Why would this be done?

Comment: Are all the sensors measuring to the same standard or accuracy?

Comment: @SolarMike Yes. I am just having an issue in fundamentally understanding why one would choose two absolutes instead of a single differential to measure a pressure drop across an orifice..